# How to create more than one group in List , SSRS 2005?

Tags: list, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am using a List in one of my reports. It has a detail grouping on a field, and controls  like subreports. Now my requirements changed a bit and I need to have an outer group around the existing one, and a page break on the outer group.

How do i do this? I tried using the same list, but couldn't figure out how to create an inner and outer grouping. Do I have to use nested lists, where the outer list has does the outer grouping and the inner list does the inner grouping?

Answer (score 5):

Your guess is correct.

You'll need to add another List control to the report.  Drag the existing List control into the new control. Under the properties for the new List control go to "Edit details group" and add to needed column to the "Group on". Next, select either "Page break at start" or "Page break at end" to add the page breaks. The rest of the report design will determine which is most appropriate.

This answer assumes that the value for the outer group is already in the dataset for the existing list. If that assumption is incorrect, you'll need to add the column into the dataset.